# PHP: Select child from array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'key1',
        'text 1 text 1 text 1'
    ),

    array(
        'key2',
        'text 2 text 2 text 2'
    ),

    array(
        'key3',
        'text 3 text 3 text 3'
    )
);
```

Sorry for the title, its quite hard to explain without an example.

The user want to read some text. For example, the text of `key2`. So when the input is `key2`, i want to display the text: `text 2 text 2 text 2`.

But how can i select that text using PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, I think using the key's as actual key's in the array:

```
$array = array("key1" => "text 1 text 1",
                "key2" => "text 2 text 2",
                "key3" => "text 3 text 3");

//now use this:
echo $array["key2"];
```

If you cannot manipulate the array, you can use a loop to create an array as described above:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $sub){
    $newArray[$sub[0]] = $sub[1];
}
```

This only works if you are sure that the key is always the first element and the text the second.

Comment: That would be a hell of a lot easier, but i can't do that, since it comes straight from the database.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution to create the array as I mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

Since it comes like that from your database (as per your comment), it depends on how often you need to do it.

There are two options, either you reformat the entire array, which will take some time, but make later look-ups faster, or you simply iterate over the array to find the key. The former solution is the best if you need to make multiple look-ups, the latter is best for a single look-up.

So, for a single look-up, you could do

```
function find_key($arr, $needle)
{
  foreach ($arr as $el)
  {
    list($key,$value) = $el;
    if ($needle == $key)
      return $value;
  }
  return false;
}

print find_key($array, 'key2'); // returns "text 2 text 2 text 2".
```

Comment: Nice combined answer of the two presented options, +1

Answer (score 1):

If you need to dynamically get wanted key, you will need to iterate over the array and match wanted "key":

```
$wanted = "key2";
$text = NULL;

foreach ( $array as $V ){
    if ( $V[0] == $wanted ){
        $text = $V[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

As @Lex suggested it's really good idea to refactor target array...